# Prometheus how to expose metrics in multiprocess app with start_http_server

Tags: python, multiprocessing, prometheus, multiprocess

How expose metrics in multiprocess app use start_http_server

I found many examples with gunicorn in internet but i want use start_http_server

what should i do with code below to make it work properly?

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time, os
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, multiprocess, CollectorRegistry, Counter


MY_COUNTER = Counter('my_counter', 'Description of my counter')
os.environ["PROMETHEUS_MULTIPROC_DIR"] = "tmp"

def f():
    print("+1")
    MY_COUNTER.inc()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_http_server(8000)
    p = Process(target=f, args=())
    a = p.start()
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=())
    p2.start()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("collect")
    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    data = multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was figuring out the same thing, and the solution was as simple as you would imagine.

Updated your example code to work:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import shutil
import time, os
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, multiprocess, CollectorRegistry, Counter


# ensure variable exists, and ensure defined folder is clean on start
prome_stats = os.environ["PROMETHEUS_MULTIPROC_DIR"]
if os.path.exists(prome_stats):
    shutil.rmtree(prome_stats)
os.mkdir(prome_stats)

MY_COUNTER = Counter('my_counter', 'Description of my counter')

def f():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("+1")
        MY_COUNTER.inc()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # pass the registry to server
    registry = CollectorRegistry()
    multiprocess.MultiProcessCollector(registry)
    start_http_server(8000, registry=registry)

    p = Process(target=f, args=())
    a = p.start()
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=())
    p2.start()

    print("collect")

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

```
localhost:8000/metrics
# HELP my_counter_total Multiprocess metric
# TYPE my_counter_total counter
my_counter_total 16.0
```